# How do i correctly initialise a controller when using Navigation bars in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, controller, navigation

I have a Navigation bar, and the list of tab widgets are all initialised in a controller called `RootController`.

I happen to add another tab  to the list called `JobsView()` but when i try to move to navigate to the tab it gives me this error:

[image: Error]

I have tried initialising the controller it said was missing but i don't really understand where it is missing because looks like all my controllers are initialized. What's the trick?

I will add the following snippets:

`JobsView()`
`root_controller`

```html
class JobsView extends GetView<EServicesController> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        child: new Icon(Icons.add, size: 32, color: Get.theme.primaryColor),
        onPressed: () => {Get.offAndToNamed(Routes.E_SERVICE_FORM)},
        backgroundColor: Get.theme.colorScheme.secondary,
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () async {
          Get.find<LaravelApiClient>().forceRefresh();
          controller.refreshEServices(showMessage: true);
          Get.find<LaravelApiClient>().unForceRefresh();
        },
        child: CustomScrollView(
          controller: controller.scrollController,
          physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: false,
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              backgroundColor: Get.theme.scaffoldBackgroundColor,
              expandedHeight: 140,
              elevation: 0.5,
              primary: true,
              pinned: false,
              floating: true,
              iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Get.theme.primaryColor),
              title: Text(
                "My Services".tr,
                style: Get.textTheme.headline6.merge(TextStyle(color: Get.theme.primaryColor)),
              ),
              centerTitle: true,
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              leading: new IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, color: Get.theme.primaryColor),
                onPressed: () => {Get.back()},
              ),
              bottom: HomeSearchBarWidget(),
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  collapseMode: CollapseMode.parallax,
                  background: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 75),
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: new LinearGradient(
                          colors: [Get.theme.colorScheme.secondary.withOpacity(1), Get.theme.colorScheme.secondary.withOpacity(0.2)],
                          begin: AlignmentDirectional.topStart,
                          //const FractionalOffset(1, 0),
                          end: AlignmentDirectional.bottomEnd,
                          stops: [0.1, 0.9],
                          tileMode: TileMode.clamp),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(5), topRight: Radius.circular(5)),
                    ),
                  )).marginOnly(bottom: 42),
            ),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Wrap(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 60,
                    child: ListView(
                        primary: false,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        children: List.generate(CategoryFilter.values.length, (index) {
                          var _filter = CategoryFilter.values.elementAt(index);
                          return Obx(() {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 20),
                              child: RawChip(
                                elevation: 0,
                                label: Text(_filter.toString().tr),
                                labelStyle: controller.isSelected(_filter)
                                    ? Get.textTheme.bodyText2.merge(TextStyle(color: Get.theme.primaryColor))
                                    : Get.textTheme.bodyText2,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 15),
                                backgroundColor: Get.theme.focusColor.withOpacity(0.1),
                                selectedColor: Get.theme.colorScheme.secondary,
                                selected: controller.isSelected(_filter),
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                showCheckmark: true,
                                checkmarkColor: Get.theme.primaryColor,
                                onSelected: (bool value) {
                                  controller.toggleSelected(_filter);
                                  controller.loadEServicesOfCategory(filter: controller.selected.value);
                                },
                              ),
                            );
                          });
                        })),
                  ),
                  ServicesListWidget(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```html
class RootController extends GetxController {
  
  final currentIndex = 0.obs;
  final notificationsCount = 0.obs;
  final customPages = <CustomPage>[].obs;
  NotificationRepository _notificationRepository;
  CustomPageRepository _customPageRepository;
  RootController() {
    _notificationRepository = new NotificationRepository();
    _customPageRepository = new CustomPageRepository();
  }

  @override
  void onInit() async {
    await getCustomPages();
    if (Get.arguments != null && Get.arguments is int) {
      changePageInRoot(Get.arguments as int);
    } else {
      changePageInRoot(0);
    }
    super.onInit();
  }
  
  List<Widget> pages = [
    HomeView(),
    JobsView(),
    ReviewsView(),
    MessagesView(),
    AccountView(),
  ];

  Widget get currentPage => pages[currentIndex.value];

  /**
   * change page in route
   * */
  void changePageInRoot(int _index) {
    currentIndex.value = _index;
  }

  void changePageOutRoot(int _index) {
    currentIndex.value = _index;
    Get.offNamedUntil(Routes.ROOT, (Route route) {
      if (route.settings.name == Routes.ROOT) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }, arguments: _index);
  }

  Future<void> changePage(int _index) async {
    if (Get.currentRoute == Routes.ROOT) {
      changePageInRoot(_index);
    } else {
      changePageOutRoot(_index);
    }
    await refreshPage(_index);
  }

  Future<void> refreshPage(int _index) async {
    switch (_index) {
      case 0:
        {
          await Get.find<HomeController>().refreshHome();
          break;
        }
      case 2:
        {
          await Get.find<MessagesController>().refreshMessages();
          break;
        }
    }
  }

  void getNotificationsCount() async {
    notificationsCount.value = await _notificationRepository.getCount();
  }

  Future<void> getCustomPages() async {
    customPages.assignAll(await _customPageRepository.all());
  }
}
```

Comment: share your code with question.

Comment: I have updated the question with my `RootController` & `JobsView()` sir. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to initialise controller before used it as mention in error logs. so you can try this:

So before use any controller in GETX you need to initialise first before use it.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Get.put(EServicesController()); // ADD this line
     return Scaffold(...);
  }
```

You learn more about GETX controller check out this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ARwxw6-GwQ)

Checkout package [Readme](https://pub.dev/packages/get) for more details.

Comment: This works! thank you.... but why so when the View is already extending the EservicesController?

Comment: before use controller we need we need to initialise controller object. by extends we just binding our UI with controller for state management. check above reference links for more details. Happy coding :)

Comment: thank you sir, i just followed on linkedin